# I need Ubuntu in dual boot with windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed ubuntu in windows8 .but dual boot is not showing. when i am starting system ,Ubuntu only getting starting. how to change in dual boot. i want get back windows8 and its files. please help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem...I use HP so I had recovery partition ,I booted into windows recovery(F11 in my case). Then went to Repair your computer...this should fix my problem But it couldn't find anything.So here is my solution:

THIS WILL NOT HARM YOUR FILES.YOU WILL GET YOUR OLD WINDOWS BACK.

go to troubleshoot in recovery menu.

Click Advanced options in Troubleshoot screen.

Click on command Prompt.

Type these following commands and hit enter after each line of command:

> Bootrec /fixmbr
>
> Bootrec /fixboot
>
> Bootrec /scanos
>
> Bootrec /rebuildbcd

It showed my C drive as windows and asked to add it as boot option .I said Y for yes and it Booted into windows 8.1 successfully.